# Eclipse incorrect variable names

Tags: java, eclipse, variables

Recently I have noticed such a thing in my Eclipse. When I create overriding Eclipse generates incorrect variable names such as `arg0, arg1, arg2` etc. Previously, she generated fine - `int position, int id`. What could be wrong?

> Sources is not included
>
> `Sources included. Source is right & they includes to build path`

Problem still here.

Comment: "Previously, he generated fine".. so eclipse IDE is MALE .. :)

Comment: @Jayesh That rules out the "it's that time of the month" answer, I guess.

Comment: @Jayesh With that many "plugins", it got to be male.

Comment: It also depends on your perspective. Get it? ... Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would happen if you override a function that you don't have source for.

Since Java bytecode does not include argument names, Eclipse can only insert them if it has the underlying source code.

Comment: This happens to me even if I have the source code!

Comment: @anakata: Then Eclipse doesn't know about it.  Check Source Attachement

Comment: @anakata Maybe your source is not linked in build path.

Comment: Source is right. And they are linked.

Comment: I've had Eclipse do this to me too; even when the source is properly attached. It happens very frequently with JDK classes.

Comment: Not JDK. JDK classes overrides normally. Android SDK it's owful:)